# Policy EntityAlreadyExists (Terraform)

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam, policy

I have a question
How can we use a resource that creates policies for several projects with the same policy name because I don't want to have 10 policies that do the same thing for several projects.
When I run the code currently I get the following error

Error: creating IAM Policy (AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole): EntityAlreadyExists: A policy called AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole already exists. Duplicate names are not allowed. status code: 409

Here is my code:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "AWSLambda" {
  statement {
    actions    = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect     = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "attach_iam_policy_to_iam_role" {
  name                = policy-iam
  assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.AWSLambda.json
  managed_policy_arns = [aws_iam_policy.policy_one.arn, aws_iam_policy.policy_two.arn]

}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy_one" {
  name = "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1::log-group:/aws/lambda/verifieASG:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
})
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy_two" {
  name = "AWSLambdaCloudFormationExecutionRole"

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
})
}
```

Comment: Do the projects have different names?

Comment: Yes, the projects have different names

Comment: Are you maybe using variables for those project names? If so, please add the variable definition to the question.

Comment: No i don't use variable for this project,v It doesn't matter, I created several iams with different names

Comment: It does matter since IAM is a global service, meaning you can have many similar IAM roles and policies (or even the same) but they have to have different names.

Comment: But, in short, you can create it once and then use data source for that: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy.